# WebAPI 2 Deployed Site Note Retrieving Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have deployed a WebAPI 2 site to a sandbox machine. The default website for the API comes up but when I hit the service's URL (e.g. http ://host/service/api/jobs), the service hangs for an indefinite period of time and doesn't return the data as it does on my development machine. Other services hosted in IIS on the machine appear to be able to connect to the SQL server database and retrieve information.

The following is my web.config for the application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="dataConnection" connectionString="connectionStringRemoved" />
      </connectionStrings>
     <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms" />
       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
       <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
       <identity impersonate="false" />
       <customErrors mode="Off" />
   </system.web>
   <system.webServer>
       <modules>
           <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
       </modules>
       <handlers>
           <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
           <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
           <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
       </handlers>
       <tracing>
           <traceFailedRequests>
               <add path="*">
                <traceAreas>
                    <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI" verbosity="Verbose" />
                </traceAreas>
                <failureDefinitions timeTaken="00:00:00" statusCodes="500" />
            </add>
        </traceFailedRequests>
    </tracing>
</system.webServer>
    <runtime>
       <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
          </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you inspected the network traffic? is the request going out?

Comment: try browsing with `http://host/api/jobs` instead of `http ://host/service/api/jobs`

Comment: @Dalorzo I had to type that with a space because SO doesn't permit host, machinename, or whatnot in the URL.

Comment: I think he means try it without the 'service' in the URL

Comment: http: //hostname/service brings up the API's default website though?!?

Comment: I meant to remove `service ` out of your url

Comment: I suppose it depends on your WebApiConfig and how its configured. Out of the box, it should be http://host/api/jobs

Comment: http ://host/api/jobs gives an 500 Internal Service Error

Comment: Can you post your WebApiConfig?

Comment: The host machine is a Windows 7 sp1 machine. Initially, when I added the service I wasn't able to even connect to the URL. I had to enable the HTTP traffic firewall rule to be able to hit the service. My strongest suspicion is that this is related to the firewall denying traffic somewhere. I am investigating the network traffic to see if that may be the case.